# How do I create a topic in Confluent Kafka deployed locally on a docker container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have deployed the kafka service locally using docker. The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
kafka-service:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0
container_name: kafka-service
ports:
  - 9092:9092
links:
  - zookeeper
environment:
  - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
  - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
  - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka-service:9092
  - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
  - KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false
```

How do I create topics for this local deployment using ccloud CLI?
Is ccloud CLI no longer supported for creating topics for locally deployed kafka brokers?
I know it was supported in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Kafka binaries files and use the kafka-topics script which is located in the bin folder. Something like this

`bin/kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 \ --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic topicname`

Alternatively you could use landoops docker image it will launch a Kafka environment and provides a UI to create topics check out this article here it is very easy

“Easy Kafka setup with docker” by Mukundh Bhushan https://link.medium.com/ReQrWuxkW3

Answer (score 0):

`ccloud` is meant to be used with **Confluent Cloud**.

You can `docker exec` into the container and run any of the commands listed in any Kafka tutorial.

Note that newer Kafka versions mostly support `--boostrap-server` in place of `--zookeeper`

Or you can use Confluent Control Center or other Docker images for creating topics